# Spring Webflow doesn't support generics in "autogrow" lists?

Tags: java, generics, spring-webflow

We are using Spring Webflow for some forms with steps. In one of them we have a list of elements that is dynamic (the user can add more elements). We use this code to do this, and works perfectly:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class AutoGrowList implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1328646310268097912L;

    @Getter
    private final List<ConcreteItemView> data;

    public AutoGrowList() {
        data = new ArrayList<ConcreteItemView>();
    }

    public AutoGrowList(List<ConcreteItemView> list) {
        data = new ArrayList<ConcreteItemView>(list);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        int index = data.size() - 1;
        for (; index >= size; index--) {
            data.remove(index);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, the type of the list elements is ConcreteItemView. We want to refactor this class to use it with other elements, using generics, like this:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class AutoGrowList<T extends AbstractView> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1328646310268097912L;

    @Getter
    private final List<T> data;

    public AutoGrowList() {
        data = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public AutoGrowList(List<T> list) {
        data = new ArrayList<T>(list);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        int index = data.size() - 1;
        for (; index >= size; index--) {
            data.remove(index);
        }
    }
}
```

But... this doesn't work... it throws an java.lang.InstantiationException in a class of Spring (Indexer.class). 
¿Spring Webflow doesn't support generics in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we fix this adding a bean SpelExpressionParser, with a SpelParserConfiguration, to our context:

```
<bean id="expressionParser" class="org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser">
        <constructor-arg name="configuration">
            <bean class="org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration">
                <constructor-arg name="autoGrowCollections" value="true" />
                <constructor-arg name="autoGrowNullReferences" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```